# How to move database calls to application server behind a firewall

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

I would like to use BreezeJS for data access in a Durandal SPA.  I have the initial app set up and working fine and uses a MVC 5 backend.

However, one of the requirements is that the public IIS server is not making calls directly to the database.  In other words, the Breeze controller should call another IIS server which is behind a firewall which then connects to Sql Server.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the basic architecture?

Comment: Updated question to include how.

Comment: Well, you have kind of answered your own question. Ultimately, you need to configure the firewall to only only http calls to the protected system and then configure your front end to communicate on the open port(s).

Comment: I doubt this is the actual requirement. A typical setup is to have the web site and database inside and expose it to the public using a reverse proxy running in the DMZ. Applications designed for this (eg SharePoint) allow a publication server/farm to run  in the DMZ with read-only or limited functionality. Putting another IIS between the web site and the database offers nothing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I will accept as answer if you post it as such.